# Images not showing after moving to LocalHost

Tags: html, server, localhost

I recently switched to developing on local host rather than on my desktop. My website works fine on the desktop but now when i run it on local host none of my images work.

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="logo.png" alt="logo" /></a>
```

That is how I'm including my images.

My localhost url is:

```
http://michaels-macbook-pro.local
```

Im getting the following error in the console:

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) (logo.png, line 0)
```

Comment: Does `logo.png` exist in your root directory?

Comment: currently yes, it is normally inside a "images" folder , but in order to get it to work i pulled it into root

Comment: Then change your `img` src to "images/logo.png"

Comment: As error says, you have no permission to access `http://michaels-macbook-pro.local/logo.png` - perhaps because you are on root?

Comment: Changed 'img' src to 'images/logo.png' still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a permissions issue.

View your file permissions in the command line with:

```
ls -l
```

You want your image files to have read access for all users. Change your permissions to something like 644 for the folder and 711 for the images:

```
chmod 644 images
chmod 711 images/logo.png
```

For info about permissions see http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uchmod.htm

You probably have the issue because you are not the 'owner' of the files on your localhost (you can also view the owner of a file using `ls -l`). So if your image files have permissions of say, 700, then only the 'owner' has read access. Whereas on your desktop you will be the owner of the files so you have read permission.

Comment: Is this just a LocalHost problem? I mean, if i put it on the web using a hosting company would I still have these issues with my images?

Comment: @MichaelBarley that depends on what your permissions are. If your images are set to say, 700, which means that you have read, write and execute permissions, but the 'group' and 'world' do not, then visitors to your site (the 'world') will not be able to 'read' the images.