# Broken image when using local host

Tags: html, image, macos, localhost

I'm embarrassed that I am unable to get this to work and I apologize in advance for the simple question. I have looked up different answers and nothing seems to work. I even tried changing the properties of the image to 'read and write' as is mentioned in another post.

[image: file structure]

You will see that both my image folder and my index.html file are in the view folder. So, when I reference the image in the index.html file, I used

```
<img src="images/portbackground1.gif" class="img-fluid" alt="Julia McGee title">
```

This works when I just preview the page in the browser. However, as soon as I try to view the page using a local host (8080), the image is broken. I have tried multiple paths including:

`view/images/portbackground1.gif` and

```
../view/images/portbackground1.gif
```

I'm not sure what I should be doing differently. I am a novice, but this was one thing I thought I knew how to do!

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you changed permissions for the file for ALL users?

Comment: Also the folder "images" need the proper permissions as well! Not just the file within. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37467363/images-not-showing-after-moving-to-localhost

Comment: I went into the image properties (on Mac, right-clicked and selected "Get Info"). I scrolled down to Sharing and Permissions and changed "staff" and "everyone" to "Read & Write." Is there another place I should be doing this?

Comment: Is your localhost running on your Mac.. Or are you using  some sandbox program?

Comment: I just changed the permissions for the folder - didn't know about that one! Still broken. :(

Comment: No, I am just running it on my Mac. I have a simple server.js file set up using Express/Node.

Comment: did u get past this?

Comment: No. :( I'm completely stumped.

Comment: Try adding the tag 'macos' to your question, since I'm almost convinced it's about permissions of folder and files. But don't know how to set it on mac.